# What Properties could be used with x:

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

In the code below why I cannot write **x:Text** in the **TextBlock** properties whereas I can write **x:Name** perfectly fine. How can I find out what properties can be prefixed with x:

```
<Window x:Class="HelloWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Hello WPF" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Hello" Text="Hello World"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a full list of the [XAML Namespace features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753327.aspx) (`x:Something`) on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate the logic behind why some properties are in this namespace whereas seemingly related properties are not in it?

Comment: @PaulSnow The namespace only has specific, xaml related properties.  `Text` is a property of the control itself, so it wouldn't be relevent for the xaml parsing directly.